# Picklist to enter text if value does not exist in the predefined list

Tags: page-layout, account, dynamic-picklist

Ideally I would want to design a Picklist field such that,  it allows users to not only select from a list of values but also allows users to write in an entry. There is a field like this on the Task object, in the Subject.

Is that possible on the Account Object, on a Standard page layout?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to do this with standard configuration. It would necessarily require code in order to make this happen.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox!  So i understand it is possible with code. In that case, can we create a lightning component to achieve this, and place it on the Account page layout?